# Pandas merge only return column names

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging two data frame in pandas.

```
df.head()
index   business_id label
0   204149  3034    0
1   48723   3034    0
2   94586   3034    0
3   74369   3034    0
4   95287   3034    0

lst.head()
index   path_to_image
0   10  ./train_photos/10.jpg
1   100003  ./train_photos/100003.jpg
2   100007  ./train_photos/100007.jpg
3   100008  ./train_photos/100008.jpg
4   100009  ./train_photos/100009.jpg
```

It only return the heads of columns.

```
pd.merge(lst, df, on='index')
index   path_to_image   business_id label
```

---

What I have checked:

1. Number of rows are equal.
2. Choose several values form one data, and I find they matches rows in the second data.
3. Both columns are of `int64`.

---

What I suspect about the reasons:

1. Missing values?
2. Duplicates?

---

Data update

```
Out[515]:
{'business_id': [3034, 3034, 3034, 3034, 3034],
 'index': [204149, 48723, 94586, 74369, 95287],
 'label': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

Out[516]:
{'index': ['10', '100003', '100007', '100008', '100009'],
 'path_to_image': ['./train_photos/10.jpg',
  './train_photos/100003.jpg',
  './train_photos/100007.jpg',
  './train_photos/100008.jpg',
  './train_photos/100009.jpg']}
```

Comment: What does `lst.index.dtype` give you? ditto for `df.index.dtype`?

Comment: Your method of describing the DataFrames is unclear (to me). Please post `df.head().to_dict('list')` and `lst.head().to_dict('list')` so we can see the raw data and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AmiTavory Checked. Both `int64`.

Comment: @unutbu I find there is a difference `204149` vs '10'. However, `dtype` return same type. What's wrong?

Comment: @unutbu Not sure how the OP did it, but I suggested using `lst.index.dtype`. Is this wrong? I'm curious, as I use it quite a lot.

Comment: @AmiTavory: Using `lst.index` would refer to the *index* of `lst`. `lst['index']` would refer to the column named `index`. So @JohnHass would need to use `lst['index'].dtype` in this case. Maybe this is a good reason why one should never refer to columns with the dot-syntax.

Comment: @unutbu Ha ha, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the values in `df['index']` are integers:

```
 'index': [204149, 48723, 94586, 74369, 95287]
```

while the values in `lst['index']` are strings:

```
'index': ['10', '100003', '100007', '100008', '100009']
```

An integer never equals a string, so there are no matches and

```
pd.merge(df, lst, on=['index'])
```

will return an empty DataFrame. To fix the problem, convert `lst['index']` to ints:

```
lst['index'] = lst['index'].astype(int)
```

before merging.

---

With the sample data you posted, `pd.merge` will return an empty DataFrame even after changing the dtype of `lst['index']` since none of the values in `[204149, 48723, 94586, 74369, 95287]` match any of the values in `[10, 100003, 100007, 100008, 100009]`. If your full DataFrames have `index` values that match, then `pd.merge` will return a non-empty DataFrame.